# I want to append list in nested list Python

Tags: python, list, append, nested-lists

```
expression = ['+', '10', 'x']
variables = {"x": (3,4)}
new_expression = []

for key, value in variables.items():
    key_index = expression.index(key)
    
    for i in range(3,5):
        expression[key_index] = i
        new_expression.append(expression)
        
print("new_expression",  new_expression)
```

Result is  new_expression = [['+', '10', 4], ['+', '10', 4]]

But I want new_expression = [['+', '10', 3], ['+', '10', 4]]

Comment: Because you keep appending *the same list*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `new_expression.append(expression)` to `new_expression.append(expression[:])` can work.
The reason is that if you append `expression`, each element within `new_expression` will points to the same object. We need to raise a new object by copying.

```py
expression = ['+', '10', 'x']
variables = {"x": (3,4)}
new_expression = []

for key, value in variables.items():
    key_index = expression.index(key)
    
    for i in range(3,5):
        expression[key_index] = i
        new_expression.append(expression[:])
        
print("new_expression",  new_expression)
```

You may want to change `for i in range(3,5):` to `for i in value:`, as you already define the values in the `variables`.

Refined version:

```py
expression_template = ['+', '10', 'x']
variables = {"x": (3,4)}
new_expression = []

for key, value in variables.items():
    key_index = expression_template.index(key)
    
    for i in value:
        expression = expression_template[:]
        expression[key_index] = i
        new_expression.append(expression)
        
print("new_expression",  new_expression)
```